# Background stretched with small window browser

Tags: html, css, reactjs, particles.js

I am using particles-js in a new React project to learn more about how it works. I have set all and managed to show it as a background while having the React logo in the middle of the page. The problem comes when the webpage is loaded in a small window and the particles are stretched. I think I am missing a CSS attribute or something but I can't figure it out.

Do you know what could be the error?

Really thank you!

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="homeContainer">
      <div id="particles-js">
        <div id="root"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--particles functions-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="%PUBLIC_URL%/particles.js"></script>
    <!--particles config-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="%PUBLIC_URL%/utilities.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

index.css:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', 'Roboto', 'Oxygen',
    'Ubuntu', 'Cantarell', 'Fira Sans', 'Droid Sans', 'Helvetica Neue',
    sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

code {
  font-family: source-code-pro, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, 'Courier New',
    monospace;
}

#root {
  z-index: 100;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

canvas {
  position : absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  z-index:-1;
}in m
```

Here some photos to see what is happening:

- Particles looking great in a big window:
  [image: Particles looking great in a big window]
- Particles stretched when loaded in a small window
  [image: Particles stretched when loaded in a small window]

UPDATE 1:
In case it can be due an error in App.css, here it is its code:

```
.App {
  text-align: center;
}

.App-logo {
  height: 40vmin;
  pointer-events: none;
}

@media (prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference) {
  .App-logo {
    animation: App-logo-spin infinite 20s linear;
  }
}

.App-header {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: calc(10px + 2vmin);
  color: white;
}

.App-link {
  color: #61dafb;
}

@keyframes App-logo-spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you remove the homeContainer div? Then add these CSS stylings:

```
#particles-js {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: $FFF;
  background-image: url("");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Comment: same result, don't know why. Seems like when loading the view the background is inside a rectangular at the top and then resizes it down creating this stretch

Comment: What happens when you divide up your root and particle divs? Like this `<div id="particles-js"></div>
        <div id="root"></div>`

Comment: Nothing changes

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me :

```
position: fixed!important;
left: 0;
right: 0;
top: 0;
visibility: visible;
}
```